# Problem with running this code in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a hard time running this:

```
Integrate[
Exp[-q^2 - (v^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2) - (u^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2)], {q, 
r/(4 a t)^(1/2), Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> a >= 0 && u >= 0 && t >= 0 && r >= 0 && v >= 0]
```

What should I do?

Comment: always try the basic integral first (indefinite) and see if that works. `Integrate[Exp[-q^2 - (v^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2) - (u^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2)], q]`  does not integrate (with or without assumptions). Either Mathematica does not know how, or this is a non integrable. You can try numerical integration.

Comment: btw, your integrand has the form    $e^{-\frac{r^2 \left(u^2+v^2\right)}{16 a^2 q^2}-q^2}$

Comment: Re *"problem"* and *"I have a hard time"*: Can you be more specific? What is happening (or not happening)? What are the symptoms? What is the problem? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/256978/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your integrand has the basic form

$$
e^{-\frac{r^2 \left(u^2+v^2\right)}{16 a^2 q^2}-q^2}
$$

Which Mathematica can't integrate. But it can integrate it when $\left(u^2+v^2\right)$ is a single symbol, like this

$$
e^{-\frac{B r^2}{16 a^2 q^2}-q^2}
$$

So by doing this replacement, (since $u,v$ do not show anywhere else), it can now do it.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
rep = (v^2 + u^2) -> b;
term = Simplify[-q^2 - (v^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2) - (u^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2)]
term = term /. rep
res=Integrate[Exp[term], {q, r/(4 a t)^(1/2), Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> a >= 0 && t >= 0 && r >= 0 , GenerateConditions -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can simply replace `b` back with `u^2+v^2`

```
res /. b -> (v^2 + u^2)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To verify the above, we can do the indefinite integration and differentiate the antiderivative to see if we get the original integrand back

```
rep = (v^2 + u^2) -> b;
term = Simplify[-q^2 - (v^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2) - (u^2 r^2/16/a^2/q^2)];
OriginalIntegrand = Exp[term];
term = term /. rep;
res = Integrate[Exp[term], q, 
   Assumptions -> a >= 0 && t >= 0 && r >= 0, 
   GenerateConditions -> False];
res = res /. b -> (v^2 + u^2);
backIntegrand = D[res, q] // Simplify;
backIntegrand == OriginalIntegrand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]